# Vague ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I build a table of values and I union it with another query.  I wish to return a set of results where one value between the 2 tables does not match. (query example below).  Every time I try to execute, I get the dreaded invalid identifier error, but I have no idea why.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
select * from (
select '1234567' as empno, 'A' as status, 'Active' as st_name from dual union all
select '89012345' as empno, 'DA' as status, 'Inactive' as st_name from dual) ft
union 
select id,status,statusnm from second_table st
where st.id = ft.empno
and st.statusnm <> ft.st_name;
```

Any thoughts/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `union`, you want `join` . . . and it should be explicit:

```
select st.*
from (select '1234567' as empno, 'A' as status, 'Active' as st_name from dual   
      union all
      select '89012345' as empno, 'DA' as status, 'Inactive' as st_name from dual
     ) ft join
     second_table st 
     on st.id = ft.empno and st.statusnm <> ft.st_name
```

Comment: I knew it was something silly.  Thank you for the insight!